# Prevent B & A entry in SQL when A & B already exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a table that contains two rows: `AccountID` and `PartnerAccountID`. I need to prevent duplicates across both columns. Meaning, if an entry exists:

```
| AccountID | PartnerAccountID |
| 1         | 2                |
```

I need to make sure that the following can't also exist:

```
| AccountID | PartnerAccountID |
| 2         | 1                |
```

Any way to do that in a constraint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be nice if you could create a unique index on an expression:

```
create unique index unq_t_AccountID_PartnerAccountID
    on t((case when AccountID < PartnerAccountID then AccountId else PartnerAccountID end),
         (case when AccountID < PartnerAccountID then PartnerAccountIDelse AccountId end)
        );
```

But you can do almost the same thing by creating the columns as computed columns and then creating the index:

```
alter table t add minid as (case when AccountID < PartnerAccountID then AccountId else PartnerAccountID end);

alter table t add maxid as (case when AccountID < PartnerAccountID then PartnerAccountIDelse AccountId end);

create unique index unq_t_minid_maxid on t(minid, maxid);
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach could also be to create an instead-of trigger which simply ignores such duplicates across two columns; The advantage would be that transactions do not need to be aborted if the information is already stored (yet the other way round). Here is an attempt of how such a trigger could look like:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_t ON t
    INSTEAD OF INSERT
  AS
  BEGIN
   INSERT t
   SELECT AccountID, PartnerAccountID
   FROM inserted
   where not exists (select * from t2 where t2.AccountID = ParnterAccountID and t2.ParnterAccountId = AccountID);
  END
```